# Issues with box drawing character interface

Tags: python, termcolor

I am working on a terminal music player. I've almost made box-drawing interface. [image: Screenshot]]

As you can see, I have broken right border (`"║"`). I tried to make it. But something is wrong and it doesn't work. Take a look at my code:

```
import vlc
import glob
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint
def scanfolder(directory, extension):
    sfile = glob.glob(f'{directory}*.{extension}')
    box1 = colored("║", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    box2 = colored("╚", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    box3 = colored("═", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    box4 = colored("╔", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    box5 = colored("╗", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    box6 = colored("╝", "yellow", attrs=["bold"])
    x = len(directory)
    y = len(extension) + 1
    z = len(max(sfile, key=len))
    z = z - x - y + 3
    box3 = box3 * z
    print(box4 + box3 + box5)
    for i, track in enumerate(sfile):
        trackEn = box1 + str(i + 1) + ". " + str(track[x:-y])
        indent = " "
        mFactor = z - len(trackEn) #z is the most long track name length, len(trackEn) is any other track's length
        indent = indent * mFactor #space * mFactor, used to align box drawing character ║, so they can make one solid wall
        print(trackEn + indent + box1) #track name + aligning spaces + ║
    print(box2 + box3 + box6)
sext = input("Choose extension: ")
sdir = input("Choose directory: ")
cprint("""
________          ________ ______                 
___  __ \_____  _____  __ \___  /______ ______  __
__  /_/ /__  / / /__  /_/ /__  / _  __ `/__  / / /
_  ____/ _  /_/ / _  ____/ _  /  / /_/ / _  /_/ / 
/_/      _\__, /  /_/      /_/   \__,_/  _\__, /  
         /____/                          /____/   """, "yellow", "on_blue", attrs=["bold"])
scanfolder(sdir, sext)
chooseTrack = colored("Choose track", "green", attrs=["bold"])
colon = colored(": ", "green", attrs=["bold", "blink"])
trackn = input(chooseTrack + colon)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Issues with box drawing character using `termcolor.colored` symbols.

The problem are the `box1` variable which is returned from `termcolor.colored`.
This string `box1` are already formated with the `ANSI` Color sequence which is, e.g. `\E231║`.
Therefore the `len(trackEn)` gives `6` more which results in `mFactor = z - len(trackEn) == -6`.
Your `mFactor` becomes Negative, therefore **no** `indent`.

---

- [life demo - repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ThisIncompleteRectangles)
- [termcolor 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/)

---

> Change the following:

```
    for i, track in enumerate(sfile):
        trackEn = str(i + 1) + ". " + str(track[x:-y])

        # z is the most long track name length, len(trackEn) is any other track's length
        mFactor = z - len(trackEn)

        # space * mFactor, used to align box drawing character ║, 
        # so they can make one solid wall 
        indent = " " * mFactor 

        # ║ + track name + aligning spaces + ║
        print(box1 + trackEn + indent + box1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. You saved my day. Finally, I can go sleep!